# Convert sequence of external commands to a Vim custom command

Tags: vimrc, command-line, external-command

To reformat Markdown tables, I use the following sequence of external commands (e.g. after visually selecting my table lines):

```
:<,>! sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}\|/\#\|/g'
:<,>! column -t -s '\#'
```

The first command prefixes each  `|` (Markdown column delimiter) with a `#`.
The second command creates aligned columns using `#` as delimiter and removes it.

I also managed to combine those in a single command:

```
:<,>! sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}\|/\#\|/g' | column -t -s '\#'
```

Now, I would like to create the corresponding custom `MDTableFormat` command somewhere in my `vimrc` file:

```
command! -range MDTableFormat ...
```

but I can't find the proper syntax for this.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax worked for me:

```
command! -range MDTableFormat <line1>,<line2>! sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}\|/\#\|/g' | column -t -s '\#'
```

Reading the documentation, I falsely assumed that `-range` was enough and `<line1>,<line2>` were placeholders for you to explicitly specify on which lines you wanted the command to apply.